# Avoid multiplication of ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a little problem with my functions.
When I execute a function which launchs an Ajax call several times, each time, it multiplicate the number of call.
For example, I want to send a commentary, the first time, all is going good. But if I want to send another, it will be send twice. And if I do it again, it will be send three times.
If you can help me, it will be great :D
Thanks in advance.

Javascript:

```
$('.modifier').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $('#error').hide();
        var form = document.querySelector('form')
        var formdata = new FormData(form);
        formdata.append('fichier', window.file[0]);
        //console.log(window.file[0]);


        $('input[name=titre]').val('');
        $('input[name=fichier]').val('');
        $('textarea[name=description]').val('');

        window.request_upload = $.ajax({
            xhr: function()
              {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                //Upload progress
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    $('.chargement').show();
                    $('.chargement> #progress_bar').css({'width' : percentComplete*100 + '%'}).text(Math.round(percentComplete*100) + '%');
                    //console.log(percentComplete);
                  }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
              },
            url: "foobar.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata, 
            async: true ,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        })
        .done(function(data){

            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            //console.log('Data : '+data);
            //console.log('L\'erreur : '+json.erreur);

            if(json.erreur == 0)
            {
                //console.log(json.titre);
                var titre = json.titre;
                $.notify('Votre photo : "'+titre+'" a bien été envoyé !',{autoHideDelay: 10000, className: 'success'});
                $('.drop_depot').removeClass('hover');
                $('.chargement').hide();
                $(this).removeClass('hover');
                $('.drop_depot').empty().append('<span>'+options.message+'</span>');
                $('.drop_depot').css({'width': '30%', 'height': '100px' });
                $(window).resize();
                $('input[type=file]').val('');
            }
            else{
                $('.chargement').hide();
                $('#error').show().after(json.erreur + ' ' + json.erreurs);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I load this script by : $.getScript() function. If it can help ...

Comment: paste the code you have tried

Comment: sounds like you are compounding click handlers on elements. Where's your code? Pretty hard to troubleshoot what we can't see

Comment: Is that getScript being sent more than once? Easy enough to check in network tab of dev tools console. Or is `$('.modifier').live('click'` inside some other event handler?

Comment: Where are you setting the $('.modifier').live('click',function(e) code? Is  there possibility that this code is called several times?

Comment: Yes it can. If this script is called several times, won't it remove the other same script ?

Comment: Otherwise, how to only call the script if it's not already called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

My problem come from the multiple execution of $.getScript() function.

But I could do this to solve it :

```
if(!$("body").data(script_bool))
{
    $.getScript(script);
    $("body").data(script_bool, true);
}
```

The `script_bool` variable is the name of the script called.

If it can help someone.